Let $A:=\{f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}): f, f'\in L^1(\mathbb{R}\}$. Then are the Schwartz functions dense in $A$ w.r.t. $\|f\|=\|f\|_1+\|f'\|_1$?
Let $A:=\{f\in C^1(\mathbb{R}): f, f'\in L^1(\mathbb{R}\}$. Then is it true that Schwartz functions are dense in $A$ with the norm $\|f\|=\|f\|_1+\|f'\|_1$.?
My guess is the above statement shoud be true. Can you please give some hints or references for this?

Yes, this is true, and even better, smooth compactly supported functions are also dense. In fact the completion of the smooth compactly supported functions for this norm is called the Sobolev space $W^{1,1}(\Bbb{R})$.

The Schwartz space is dense in $W^{k,p}(\mathbb R^n)$ (1), so it is in particular dense in $W^{1,1}(\mathbb R^n)$ which has the norm $$\lVert u\rVert=\sum_{|\alpha|\leq 1}\lVert D^\alpha u\rVert_1 = \lVert u\rVert_1+\lVert Du\rVert_1.$$
